# Capturing remote VNC to x264 without storing first

Tags: vnc, ffmpeg, recording

I'm looking for a way to capture a remote VNC display into a local h.264 recording without having to record first in another format and then convert it after the fact. I'd see that it's is possible to use ffmpeg with the x11grab device, but that doesn't seem to work for VNC desktops.

I also looked into using rfbproxy, but it doesn't provide a stream output. It requires you to record first, then stream to stdout in an export format from the recorded file. I attempted to use a named pipe to get around this, but it didn't work.

I want to be able to record 8 hours worth of screen content and then have it available in h.264 nearly immediately after the 8 hours have completed. Also, the machines that will be doing this do not have the storage space for intermediate, lossless formats.

Any ideas?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: Run a VNC client for the remote display on a virtual X server (Xvfb), use `x11grab` on that server. A bit inefficient, but should work. Second thing that comes to mind: Copy enough code of vncclient into ffmpeg to give it some kind of `vncgrab` device, after looking at the code of `x11grab`. Most efficient way, but needs a bit of time, and programming knowledge.